# c# PropertyGrid Edit array with enum keys

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, propertygrid

I have a property which is

```
int [] MyProperty {get;set;}
```

I have a list of enums

```
enum MyEnums
{
    ENUM1=0
    ENUM2=1
    ENUM3=2
}
```

The property MUST be an int array due to tools that run on the code serializing the property out to a file.
I'd like my property grid to allow me to edit MyProperty displaying the enum names as the keys rather than 0,1 and 2. The array must be the same length as the enum list so no members can be added or removed. I imagine I need a custom editor to achieve this? Can anyone make any suggestions of the best way to achieve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary in this case

```
Dictionary<MyEnums, int> MyProperty {get; set;}
```

Also, you can implement your own "wrapper" class and and add an indexer for it using MyEnums
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/a0h36syw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for enum values. Also it seems your direction about the property editing is not that corrent. You can create a class for example:

```
class EnumPropHolder
{
   MyEnums Prop1 = MyEnums.Enum1 {get;set;}
   MyEnums Prop2 = MyEnums.Enum2 {get;set;}
   //etc.
}
```

so now this makes you able to use your class instance as the object for the PropertyGrid in the way you are talking about